# Windows11 Notepad cannot find by FindWindowEx in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, notepad

I want to find notepad in Windows 11 by using vb.net source.
But I always get notepad window not found error.
I think Windows 11 notepad is changed style that is the main reason.
It totally work in windows 10.

Here is my code sample.
Please sugguest me.

```vb
<System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)>
Private Shared Function FindWindowEx(
                                    ByVal hwndParent As Integer,
                                    ByVal hwndChild As Integer,
                                    ByVal lpClassName As String,
                                    ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr


End Function

Private Sub btnShow_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnShow.Click
        Dim VM_SETTEXT As String = &HCS
        Dim source As String = "hello world"
        Dim p As New Process
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe"       
        p.Start()     
       
        Dim hwnd = FindWindowEx(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, "Notepad", "")

        If hwnd <> IntPtr.Zero Then
            MessageBox.Show("Find notepad window")
        End If
End Sub
```

I want to find Notepad window in Windows 11 to send data to Notepad.

Comment: Settings > Apps > Advanced > App execution aliases > turn it off for notepad.

Comment: You should be calling `FindWindow` to find a top-level window and then `FindWindowEx`  to find the child windows of that, if required. I very much doubt that that window's class name is "Notepad" either.

Comment: Also, given that you're starting the Notepad process yourself, you may be able to just get the `MainWindowHandle` of your process. That may not work, now that Notepad has tabs, but you'd almost certainly have to call `WaitForInputIdle` if it was to work.

Comment: @jmcilhinney `FindWindowEx(nullptr, a, b)` is the same as `FindWindow(a, b)`. It's a little more typing, but otherwise identical. The OP just need a tool like spyxx to confirm that the window they are looking for matches the search criteria they are passing.

Comment: Actually, I take that back. I just used Spy++ and the class name is indeed "Notepad". I don't think that used to be the case but, regardless, it is now.

Comment: I think the issue is that you are using an empty string for the window name. Your window caption is almost certainly not an empty string, so that won't match. Use `Nothing` instead to match any caption. Note that I tested that with and without Has Passant's suggestion and it worked for me.

Comment: _I want to find Notepad window in Windows 11 to send data to Notepad_: No one ever wants to send data to Notepad because it's not necessary. One can easily create a text file using other methods. What are you really trying to achieve?  To be able to send keystrokes to other Windows? Perhaps to automate playing a game. Maybe trying to break into some computer system, etc... Please state your intentions. Maybe you're the student referenced in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77825805/discourage-users-from-unplugging-mouse-and-keyboard-from-pc)?

Answer (score 3):

Based on my testing, this:

```vb
Dim hwnd = FindWindowEx(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, "Notepad", "")
```

should be this:

```vb
Dim hwnd = FindWindowEx(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, "Notepad", Nothing)
```

As you have it, it will only match a window where the caption is an empty string. By specifying `Nothing`, you tell it to match any caption.

Also, you have declared the first two parameters to be type `Integer` but then you pass `IntPtr` values. That will work if you have `Option Strict Off` but you definitely should not have `Option Strict Off`, so that should not compile. Either declare the parameters as type `IntPtr` or pass `Integer` values. You should set `Option Strict On` in the project properties and also in the VS options, so it will be `On` by default for all future projects.

Comment: It work well .Thanks alot.But I am facing another problem. I want to make to find Notepad and send data to Notepad. by using "SendMessage" API function. Please can you help me. I am a new VB.net learner.I try it with SendMessage but It did not work.

Comment: If it worked well then it has addressed your issue and you should accept the answer. If you have another issue then you should post another question containing all and only the information relevant to that issue. The comments on the answer to one question is not the place to ask a new question unless it is specifically about that answer. All questions must be asked separately on SO, even if they are related. You can always provide a link to this question for additional background, if it adds value. The new question should probably include your updated code based on this answer.

Comment: thanks for your advice. I will post another question

Comment: I post another question. Please give me any suggesstion.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77839493/write-data-to-notepad-with-sendmessage-api-function-not-work-in-windows11